# Spring boot WebFlux: WebFilter not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have the below controller which returns a Mono of string

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/test")
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping
    public Mono<String> getDraft() {
        return Mono.just("ok");
    }

}
```

I added the bean WebFilter to do some treatment when a request comes in, the problem is that the message in the bean does not display in the console, i tried to add a breakpoint to debug but when i test the api it's not stopping in the breakpoint. In the `actuator/beans` i found the bean `slf4jMdcFilter`. There's another config to add ?

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    public static final String TRX_ID = "transactionId";
    public static final String PATH_URI = "pathUri";

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    WebFilter slf4jMdcFilter() {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            System.out.println("Filtering request");
            String requestId = exchange.getRequest().getId();
            return chain.filter(exchange)
                    .contextWrite(Context.of(TRX_ID, requestId)
                            .put(PATH_URI, exchange.getRequest().getPath()));
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved by using [deferContextual(Function)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/3.4.11/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#deferContextual-java.util.function.Function-)
& [transformDeferredContextual(BiFunction)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/3.4.11/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#transformDeferredContextual-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

```java
@Component
public class YourFilter implements WebFilter {

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    return Mono.deferContextual(contextView -> chain.filter(exchange)
        .contextWrite(context -> context.put("KEY", "VALUE")));
  }
}

// controller
 @Override
  public Mono<String> testApi(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return Mono.just("OK")
        .transformDeferredContextual((data, context) -> {
          log.info("context is {}", (Object) context.get("KEY"));
          return data;
        });
  }
```